# Backbone collection always with n models

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

I'm trying make a list with last ten models or less on collection. I have events to add models dynamically with create. This event calls 'add' on collection and with my logic this add correctly one element. But I need add new element, check if collection has more than 10, if it's true remove last model and add new

```
var model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: function() {
    return {id:null}
  }
});

var collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
     model:model
});

var view = Backbone.View.extend({
   initialize: function(){
    var self = this;
    this.listenTo(collection, 'add', this.addOne);
    this.listenTo(collection, 'reset', this.addAll);
    this.listenTo(collection, 'all', this.render);
   },
   render: function(){
    this.$el.html();
return this;
   },
   addAll: function(){
this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);
   },
   addOne: function(model){
    //this is executed after 'create' but before this I need slice my collection
var view = new view({model:model});
this.$el.prepend(view.render().el);
   }
});
```

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Bind a function in `initialize` of your `Backbone.Collection.extend` on the `add` event in which you're checking the size.

```
initialize: function() {            
    this.on('add', function() {
        this.checkSize();
    });
},

checkSize: function() {
    var max = 10;

    if (this.length > max) {
        this.reset(this.first(max));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yoou can do like that:

```
   addOne: function(model){
      //this is executed after 'create' but before this I need slice my collection
      if !model.get('new_field')
         model.set({new_field, ""})
      newField = new Date();
      while (this.collection.findWhere({new_field:newField})){
         newField = new Date();
      }
      model.set({new_field, newField});
      var view = new view({model:model});
      this.$el.prepend(view.render().el);
      this.checkLength()
   },
   checkLength: function(){
      if (this.collection.length > 10) {
          // remove model which gets minimum value by 'new_field'
      }
   }
```